# LINQ to Entities v/s ADO.Net

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

Can LINQ to Entities entirely replace ADO.Net technology?

What I really want to know is, Is it possible to achieve every features and functionality that ADO.Net provides by using LINQ ?  Who is the Boss?

Comment: I think you mean `LINQ-to-Entity` and `LINQ-to-SQL`, so the answer is NO, ADO.NET is some kind of *lower level*. You can still use it for some improvement on speed (but not really much) and some old pattern. Your question is similar to *Can C# replace C++?*, as far as I know `LINQ-to-Entity` is built on top of `ADO.NET`.

Comment: My question was between Linq-to-Entity and Pure ADO.Net coding to access DB.

Comment: Linq2Entity is just set of classes, which hides ado.net calls, data-code mapping and a lot of other stuff from you. Linq2Entity helps us access to DB data in less "low-leveler" manner. So real answer be "ADO.NET is the Boss".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said in your comment that you mean LINQ to Entities, I will answer thus:

LINQ to Entities internally use ADO.Net, so it would be impossible for LINQ to Entities to replace ADO.Net, because it uses it. However I am assuming that you mean to ask if you can use LINQ to Entities in every situation that you could use ADO.Net. The answer is no, you cannot.

There are cases that you would not want to (or could not) use LINQ to Entities. For example if you are in a certain situation where you need better performance for a query, it would be better to use a stored procedure. Generally LINQ to Entities is a better choice when developer productivity has a higher priority than the execution speed of queries. Other cases where LINQ to Entities is not a good choice is when a DB has been poorly designed and does not have a primary key for example.

But the main point I think is this: What has higher priority in your situation? Developer productivity or performance? It is also quite acceptable I think to use both technologies. Complete the project with LINQ to Entities, and if there are performance issues, use stored procedures or ADO.Net.

Also, I would not use LINQ to Entities for large queries, or queries that have many joins, LINQ syntax for joins is not very terse, and may hurt the readability of your code.

Comment: Thank you. This was brief enough.

Answer (score 1):

@Reddy, it entirely depends on the scenario where you are deciding which technology to use. ADO.NET gives you tuple structure using DataSet at its focus and is used even day compared to ORM like tech i.e. LINQ-Entity. I have refrained to ADO.NET when the prime aspect of the application revolves around record processing, used in the SSIS pipeline but have stuck to LINQ-Entity when I primarily follow Test Driven Development or Domain Driven Development approaches.

Answer (score 0):

1)ADO.NET is the database connectivity technology, so we can use ado.net to do operations with only Databases , but if we get a requirement to get the data from non database datasources like xml,collections etc.. its not possible.
But using LINQ it is possible to get data from many datasources like collections, XML files, Entities, even with Databases also.

2) But if you come to the performance wise ADO.NET is very faster than any other database connective technologies.

3) If you go with LINQ Run time errors can be rectified so bugs will be less ,so reliability increases

```
  so ADO.NET vs LINQ technologies both having their own positives and negative features ,Microsoft given huge amount of featured technologies, so according to the application requirement we need to go with that technology.
```

Comment: Let me correct this:

1. & 2. Not true. ADO.NET is just a framework which gives u many ways how to operate with data via drives (ole db, odbc). You can use any source of data as long as driver can handle it.

3. Intely-sense due to strong type approach is what you are talking about, reliability is questionable